# Ожидаемое количество товара

Tags: php, moysklad-json-api

Есть ли возможность получить по API данные о числах ожидаемоq доставки. 
Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зависит от того, есть ли этот API...

Answer (score 0):

Если верить [документации](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html#header-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8), то такой возможности нет.